# Run Helm commands using python script

Tags: python, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I wanted to run "helm repo add datawire https://app.getambassador.io " using python scripts. I researched and found this link  https://github.com/andriisoldatenko/pyhelm/blob/master/pyhelm/repo.py. But I didn't find that I needed. Could you help me with that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run commands with Python, the best way is to use `subprocess`, it's very easy and works great, usually.

Here's an example:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call(['helm',  'repo' 'add', 'datawire', 'https://app.getambassador.io/'])
```

Notice that this will just call the helm client and wait for it to complete. If the command which you started returns with error, then an `Exception` will be thrown.

If you need the `stdout` output of the command, you can instead use `check_output`.

---

Subprocess documentation can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)